# Select только тех записей из таблицы которые были изменены. Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

Можно конечно добавить к таблице с данными зависимую таблицу с полями для хранения изменений.

Но можно ли как-то только силами sql Postgres вытащить только те строки из таблицы, которые были изменены допустим за последний час?

Comment: В таблице должна быть колонка UpdatedOn со временем последнего обновления. Тогда запрос будет тривиальным. | Возможно, вам нужны Temporal tables (History tables). Для постгреса есть расширение.

Comment: а если это расширение подключить тогда запрос будет приблизительно каким?

Comment: Без штампа времени последнего изменения, только на основании текущего состояния, задача не решается в принципе. При наличии только срезов задача также не решается - невозможно отличить неизменённую запись от изменённой с последующим обратным изменением.

Comment: А зачем вам расширение, добавьте колонку, как порекомендовали в первом комментарии. И например в триггере обновляйте ее значение. И запрос тогда будет `select * from table where UpdatedOn  > now() - intreval '1 hour'`